# String.Replace more occurrences of subsequent characters

Tags: c#, .net, string

Recently I used the String.Replace method to ensure that user input, which was later included into a HTML comment, is properly sanitized. I needed that input for later use so HttpUtility.HtmlEncode was not a choice.

What my code did was calling String.Replace("--", "- -") on the input. However, I realized that the Replace function did not behave as I expected. For example:

```
var userData = "----";
return userData.Replace("--", "- -"); // returns "- -- -", I expected "- - - -"
```

or:

```
var userData = "---";
return userData.Replace("--", "- -"); // returns "- --", I expected "- - -"
```

In the second example you can see, that this sanitization is useless and a malicious user can actually still end the comment.

Now my questions:

1. Is this considered intended behavior for String.Replace?
2. Can I easily achieve the output I intended to achieve?

Note: I know there are other ways to sanitize the output (eg. replacing the hyphens with underscores), but I am interested it this particular way (ie. spaces between -- subsequent dashes).

Comment: Yes, this is intended behavior of `Replace` since it matches with first `--`.

Comment: Looks like entirely reasonable behaviour of `Replace` IMO. I'd be surprised if it did anything else.

Comment: are you aware you escape function generates ambiguous results? if you escape `- --`, you get `- - -`, unescaping it would get `-- -`...

Comment: @SonerGönül - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx - Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

Comment: ...Frankly, I'd probably still HtmlEncode it.  Comments aren't really meant to be seen or used as data, so if you're planning on reading the _exact_ value from the comment, you're doing something wrong.  For that matter, I'm not sure why you'd allow user-specified, dynamic comments in the first place.

Comment: @Luizgrs yes I am, I dont care about the dashes, I just need chars like "žťš" or arabic letters not being encoded

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I know, it was legacy code, and there was not space for refactoring. It is actually used for a search function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the intended behavior because your call to `Replace` is only making one pass at the string.  Thus, every instance of "-" in your string is being replaced by "- -", each of which is abutting one another, e.g. "- -" next to "- -" next to "- -" and so on, which looks like this: "- -|- -|- -" (<-- vertical lines added for clarity).

Just run the replace a second time to clean up the abutting "-" characters that result from the first replace:

```
var result = userData.Replace("--", "- -").Replace("--", "- -");
```

I would also like to point out that, while for small examples this type of direct string manipulation is fine, you would want to consider using a [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) if you are going to broaden this to larger or more iterative string manipulation.  Each time you modify a `string` (i.e. by concatenating, appending, or calling `Replace`), a *new* string is created in memory because strings are *immutable*.  A `StringBuilder`, on the other hand, gets around this problem by working with a mutable collection of characters and only produces a `string` at the end when you call `ToString`.

Here is how you could do the same thing with a `StringBuilder`

```
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(userData);
var result = sb.Replace("--", "- -").Replace("--", "- -").ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, this won't really solve the problem as the user can simply use 7 hyphnes to end the comment. But I see your point.

Comment: @bayo15 -- you're going to need to clarify that.  This answers your question as it is currently written; if there is some condition (as you have just mentioned) regarding different behavior at the end of a string, then you should have provided that in your original question.  You cannot, however, modify your question now because people have answered it as it is currently written, and if you modify it substantively, it will make the existing answers not make sense.  Doing so is against the rules.

Comment: I thought describing this as a problem of sanitizing user input made clear that the cases provided in the code examples are not the only to be considered. Anyway, thanks for the rich explanation. I'll try to be more specific next time.

Comment: @bayo15 - It doesn't matter how many hyphens the user types: the first pass replaces all pairs of "--" with "- -", which will create new pairs on the boundary between the original pairs. But the second pass fixes that without creating extra pairs, as these pairs are all separated by spaces..

Comment: @HansKesting You are right! Totally overlooked this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered to work with `RegEx`? There is a `RegEx.Replace()` method and you can handle different variations and occurrences with appropriate `RegEx` pattern

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx

```
RegEx.Replace(stringToReplaceAndTest,"/-/g"," -");
```

This RegEx will look for dashes globally and replaces them with and blank+dash... 
But like I said you just have to find the right pattern... 
HTH

Answer (score 0):

`string.Replace` does one pass through string. to achieve your expectations, do

```
while(userData.Contains("--"))
{
     userData = userData.Replace("--", "- -");
}
```

Comment: `Replace` returns new string. It doesn't (can't) change the original one since it is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

1. String.Replace does what you want once. (returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.) [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. I would do it like,

   ```
   public static class StringExtensions
   {
       public static string ReplaceAllOccurrences(
           this string str,
           string oldValue,
           string newValue)
       {
           var result = str;
           while (result.Contains(oldValue))
           {
               result = result.Replace(oldValue, newValue);
           }

           return result;
       }
   }


   [TestClass]
   public class ReplaceAllOccurencesTest
   {
       [TestMethod]
       public void Test()
       {
           var userData = "----";
           var replaced = userData.ReplaceAllOccurrences("--", "- -"); // returns "- -- -", I expected "- - - -"
           Assert.AreEqual(replaced, "- - - -");

           userData = "---";
           replaced = userData.ReplaceAllOccurrences("--", "- -"); // returns "- --", I expected "- - -"
           Assert.AreEqual(replaced, "- - -");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx - Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

Comment: @bayo15 yes you are right. I corrected it and thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be useful:

```
var userData = "----";
userData = Regex.Replace(userData, @"-{1}", " -").TrimStart();
```